# Implicit conversion and string::operator=()

Tags: c++, c++11, type-conversion, implicit-conversion

I have a problem with implicit conversion.

I have class `ConfigValue` and it contains two types of values - int and string. Yes, I need to store these two types, because config file contains some int an some string values.
This class has implemented two conversion operators:

```
ConfigValue::operator int() const {
    if( m_type != TYPE_INT )
        throw ConfigException( ConfigException::ERR_INVALID_TYPE, m_key );
    return m_ival;
}
ConfigValue::operator  std::string() const {
    if( m_type != TYPE_STRING )
        throw ConfigException( ConfigException::ERR_INVALID_TYPE, m_key );
    return m_sval;
}
```

The next class is `Config` and it has map of values:`<std::string, ConfigValue>`. Sometimes I need to get some value, so it has implemented method get:

```
const ConfigValue & Config::get( const std::string& key) const {
    auto pos = m_values.find( key );
    if( pos == m_values.end() )
        throw ConfigException( ConfigException::ERR_MISSING_KEY, key );
    return m_values.at(key);
}
```

And my question and problem goes here:

```
// error: error: ambiguous overload for ‘operator=’ in ‘msg =
// in one of candidates:
// no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const ConfigValue’ to ‘const char*’
string msg;
msg = config->get("DEFAULT_MSG");

// ok:      
int port;
port = config->get("DEFAULT_PORT");
// ok:
string msg;
msg = static_cast<string>( config->get("DEFAULT_MSG") );
// ok:
string msg;
string tmp = config->get("DEFAULT_MSG");
msg = tmp;
```

So if I try to assign the value from get() to already created string object, it fails.
I tried to implement `operator char*()` but I got the same error and "no known conversion .." disappears.

Do I have to implement another conversion operator or something else to use it without static_cast?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't the need for those implicit conversions because of over-engineering with `ConfigValue`? It seems to be constructed without need for it. Without it you can get what you need directly from config and all seems more clear and type-safe:

```
string msg;
msg = config->getString("DEFAULT_MSG");

int port;
port = config->getInt("DEFAULT_PORT");
```

Comment: What do you mean by "over-engineering"? And yes, using int/string getters is probably more clear so I'll rewrite it. But type-safe .. if an exception is thrown always the type inside ConfigValue does not match, it cause the program to shut down. So I think that it is sufficient.

Comment: With "over-engineering" I meant that there seems to be class whose only responsibility seems to be forwarding things from anyway known source. With "more type-safe" I meant that implicit conversions may cause some typos to compile without type-related diagnostics. The compile-time diagnostics are commonly considered better safety than run-time exceptions/errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
ConfigValue::operator  std::string() const
```

to

```
ConfigValue::operator const std::string&() const
```

If that doesn't solve your problem, you might be stuck adding explicit getters for the int and string types

Comment: Same error. I don't understand, why it works for ints but not for strings :/